# Better dots for infinite continued fraction

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, fractions

My question is related to the out put of following code. I want the `\ddots` to start from the center of the plus sign and continue diagonally. The way it is right now is bit odd. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\cofrac}[2]{%
  {%
    \rlap{$\dfrac{1}{\phantom{#1}}$}%
    \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{0}{}{#1+#2}%
  }%
}
\[
\sqrt{x} =~ \cfrac{1}{a_1+\cfrac{1}{a_2+\cfrac{1}{a_3+\cfrac{1}{a_4+{\ddots}}}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

I just placed the `\ddots` inside a `\raisebox` of `-.33\height`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\cofrac}[2]{%
  {%
    \mathrlap{\dfrac{1}{\phantom{#1}}}%
    \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{0}{}{#1+#2}%
  }%
}
\[
\sqrt{x} =~ \cfrac{1}{a_1+\cfrac{1}{a_2+\cfrac{1}{a_3+\cfrac{1}{a_4+\raisebox{-.33\height}{\(\ddots\)}}}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks better. Thank you.